# Merge Power BI is blocked

Tags: mongodb, microsoft-powerbi

I have data divide into three

- Data from customers (10 000 lines)
- Location data (10 000 rows for each table)
- Traffic data Sflow (18 000 000 lines)
  that I stored in MongoDB.

On Power BI when I am merging traffic flow and location data it hangs in waiting for dsn, whereas any other merge that does not contain Sflow data works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that scale I would not expect good performance doing a Merge in the Query engine.

Instead I would try to pull the 3 tables in separately and combine them using relationships in the Model view, or push the Merge logic back to the MongoDB server e.g. using a view.

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain more what should I do?

Comment: I prefer the first option, so pull the 3 MongoDB tables in 3 separate Queries.  Then go to the Model view and create relationships between the tables.  I would use the same columns you were trying to match on in your Merge steps.

Comment: Once the relationships are set, you can typically use any column from any related table in any visual.  It should also Refresh about as fast as MongoDB can pump out the data.

Comment: It doesn't work.. I face the same problem

Comment: I dont follow. Your problem was when you Merged to a large table. If you've followed my advice you've taken that step out, which you said runs quickly?

Comment: When I tried what you said it gives me that  
you can not create a relationship between these two columns because one of them must contain unique values

Comment: It worked one of the table was containing empty fields that's why Thank you sooo much